# Django PermissionDenied return error 500 instead of 403

Tags: python, django

So, in my Django 4.0 project, I have a Class-Based View that inherits `UserPassesTestMixin`.
If the `test_func` returns False it throws a `PermissionDenied` exception which in its turn must return `403.html`
But instead of *403*, I'm getting a *500* server error.
I read in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/views/) that PermissionDenied must trigger the django.views.defaults.permission_denied, but it doesn't.
Please give me some advice.

```
class PostListView(UserPassesTestMixin, HomeView, ListView):
    template_name = "diary/post_list.html"
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    permission_denied_message = "Access for staff only!"
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff
```

I solved it by *catching* `PermissionDenied` exception in `handle_no_permission`:

```
def handle_no_permission(self):
        try:
            return super().handle_no_permission()
        except PermissionDenied as e:
            return permission_denied(self.request, e)
```

But it looks unnatural...

Comment: A 500 server error when run with the Django development server, will usually show a backtrace, both in the browser and in the terminal. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Set `DEBUG = True` and look at the traceback. There can be many different errors that cause 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was due to using of my custom `middleware` that catches all unhandled exceptions and returns 500 errors (and logs them).
So I have just caught the PermissionDenied exception **there** and returned the right 403 error.
Overdone a little with middleware. Thanks to all.